# Bash aliasing not replacing as expected

Tags: bash

I am trying to alias the name of an S3 bucket to save having to enter it constantly when transferring files.

In my .bash_profile:

```
alias as3="aws s3"
alias artifacts="s3://dev-artifacts-bucket-name"
alias admin="--profile admin-user"
```

Example desired command using aliases:

```
as3 cp localFile.txt artifacts/ admin
```

Which should resolve to:

```
aws s3 cp localFIle.txt s3://dev-artifacts-bucket-name/ --profile admin-user
```

Where "admin-user" is the name of an IAM role configured in my ~/.aws/config file.

Instead I get the error:

```
as3 cp ./upload.sh artifacts/ admin

Unknown options: admin
```

or when I eliminate the profile alias

```
as3 cp ./upload.sh artifacts/ --profile admin-user

usage: aws s3 cp <LocalPath> <S3Uri> or <S3Uri> <LocalPath> or <S3Uri> <S3Uri>
Error: Invalid argument type
```

The error message clearly shows the first alias working since I get the "aws s3" usage error, but the second alias does not get triggered. Tried debugging with set -x and got:

```
as3 cp upload.sh artifacts admin
+ aws s3 cp upload.sh artifacts admin
```

Unless bash detects recursive alias substitution and stops it with an obtuse error, I'm at a loss for what is happened.

FYI: I'm a self declared bash noob, be gentle.
(yes, I sourced the .bash_profile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing `alias` in Bash with variables. An `alias` can only be used as the start of a command.

The arguments can instead be variables:

```
alias as3="aws s3"
artifacts="s3://dev-artifacts-bucket-name"
admin="--profile admin-user"
```

Then you can:

```
as3 cp localFile.txt $artifacts/ $admin
```

Comment: I would use `as3 cp localFile.txt "${artifacts}/" "${admin}"`.

Comment: `$admin` cannot be quoted, since it contains two words intended as separate arguments. Neither variable needs to be exported, but `admin` either needs to be left unquoted, or replaced with an array `admin=(--profile admin-user)` followed by `as3 cp localFile.txt "$artifacts/" "${admin[@]}"`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than defining several separate variables, just define one function to wrap the entire command:

```
upload_as_admin () {
    aws s3 cp "$1" s3://dev-artfacts-bucket-name --profile admin-user
}
```

To use it, pass the file to upload as the argument:

```
upload_as_admin localFile.txt
```

Comment: This would only solve this exact use case. The intention is to be able to do arbitrary operations like list, delete and build composable shortcuts.

Comment: There are certain things you just can't use variables alone for, though. See my comment to Will's answer.